# How to remove a dataframe in R by a string variable?

Tags: r

I have a question.

For example, I would like to remove a dataframe, `df_to_remove`, in R.

I can remove it in this way: `rm("df_to_remove")`.

If I set a string variable called dataframe_name.
`dataframe_name = "df_t_remove"`

Why the following commend does not work?
`rm(eval(dataframe_name))`?

How to remove a dataframe in R by a string variable?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this often. If you are, it may be time to learn about [lists of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/4497050) and [list columns](https://github.com/cwickham/purrr-tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `list =` argument in `rm()`:

```
x <- 5
y <- 'x'
rm(list = y)
```